# How can I force a writable computed observable to write with Javascript

Tags: knockout.js, jasmine

I'm trying to create a unit test with Jasmine and I'd like to check if my computed Observable really writes, what it writes. For that I need to know how I can make it write and how I can test the output.

Let's say we have a pureComputed Observable here

```
#coffeescript
@myComputedObservable = ko.pureComputed
 read: ->
  if @x = @y then return 'not here'
 write: (val) -> return
 owner: @
```

Now I'd like to test it.

```
describe 'myComputedObservable', ->
 it 'can write', ->
  myObject.myComputedObservable.write #what comes here, how can it write?
  expect(myObject.myComputedObservable()).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript, but that `write` function seems to be a noop: it just returns straight away? Or is this the "red" test of red-green-refactor TDD?

Comment: Yes, that would be TDD, but I'm focusing on code coverage and there this part is marked in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `ko.pureComputed(...)` (or `ko.computed(...)`) you get back a function, but that function will *not* have `read` or `write` properties. Instead, you get back a *function* with two "modes":

- GET, with `myComputedObservable()`: invoke it *without* arguments, which will invoke the "hidden" `read` function you provided when creating it.
- SET, with `myComputedObservable("Some value")`: invoke it *with* an argument, which will invoke the "hidden" `write` function you provided when creating it.

So you need the *second* form to indirectly call the `write` function and test that.

Of course you do need to make sure the `write` function actually does something, or else you won't be testing that bit at all.

Here's a (non coffeescript) example:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var x = ko.observable("something"), y = ko.observable("another thing");
      
  this.myComputedObservable = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() { 
      if (x() === y()) return 'not here'; 
      return undefined; 
    },
    write: function(val) { 
      x(val);
    }
 }, this);
}

describe('myComputedObservable', function() {
  var myObject;
  
  beforeEach(function() { myObject = new ViewModel(); });
  
  it('can write', function() {
    myObject.myComputedObservable("another thing");
    expect(myObject.myComputedObservable()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.min.js"></script>
```

You will also note I needed to tweak some other things for that demo:

- `x` and `y` are observables, which is needed or else `read` will not be reevaluated when they change;
- as such, they are invoked as functions (with empty parentheses to get values, with a value to set it);
- I made the `return undefined` behavior explicit, for clarity
- I added some testing values for `x`, `y`, and the actual test;
- a ViewModel and `beforeEach` was needed to bootstrap a minimal repro that makes sense

Also beware that you should switch from `pureComputed` to a `computed` when the read function is no longer a pure function. See the docs for more info.

Comment: Thanks, Jeoren, I tried it before asking this question. I am confused, because in my case there was an error saying that myObject.myComputedObservable.write ("someValue") is not a function. But I'm happy to try it out again once I am on my computer.

Comment: @Lintu The result of `ko.pureComputed` is actually a function which does *not* have `read` or `write` properties. Instead, the `read` bit is "hidden" behind `myComputedObs()` whereas the `write bit is "hidden" behind `myComputedObs(newVal)`.

Comment: Thank you Jeoren, this helped a lot. Also, I think we should change the expect function. Since it returns a function or in other words, {}, the following is better when testing: expect(myObject.myObservable "foo").toEqual(jasmine.any(Object)) according to the Jasmine documentation: "Matching Anything with jasmine.any"

Comment: Ah yeah sure. I usually use QUnit so I may not have followed Jasmine best practices, as I was focussing mainly on how-to write to a computed. Glad it helped.